# Compare file pattern in file

Tags: python, compare

How compare a file with patterns in another file

- File with patterns (patterns.txt)

  ```
  pattern1
  pattern2
  pattern3
  ```
- File (file.txt)

  ```
  something1
  something3
  pattern1
  something4
  something5
  pattern2
  something6
  pattern3
  something7
  ```
- Script

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python

  import sys

  patternFile = sys.argv[1]
  fileName = sys.argv[2]

  with open(patternFile, 'r') as file_open:
      for pattern in file_open:
              with open(fileName, 'r') as file_to_compare:
                      if pattern in file_to_compare:
                              print pattern
  ```

It isn't working; what am I missing?

./searchPattern.py patterns.txt file.txt

Thanks

Comment: What is not working please post your error message

Comment: That is the question, I do not get error! I don't receive none answer, it is not matching in file

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried something like this :

```
patternList = open(patternFile, 'r')
patternListLines = patternList.readlines() 
fileTXT = open(fileName , 'r')

def checkPattern(patternList ,x):
    if x in patternList:
        return True

matchPattern=[x for x in fileTXT.readlines() if checkPattern(patternList, x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

- I didn't, but it is working now.
- I added **for line in file_to_compare:**
- It **worked now!**

Sctipt:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import sys 
patternFile = sys.argv[1] 
fileName = sys.argv[2] 
with open(patternFile, 'r') as file_open: 
    for pattern in file_open: 
        with open(fileName, 'r') as file_to_compare: 
            for line in file_to_compare: 
                if pattern in line: print pattern 

./searchPattern.py patterns.txt file.txt 
pattern1 
pattern2 
pattern3
```